# Why do circuit simulators like LTSpice prefer current sources instead of voltage sources?

Tags: ltspice, spice

I was having trouble with a "time step too small" error, and came across [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/405979/ltspice-error-timestep-too-small/405985) explaining that "stiff" equations gives LTSpice problems. Looking into [LTSpice's documentation](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Convergence_problems%3F), they say that:

> It can't be stressed enough that stiff voltage sources (especially
> nonlinear behavioral types) are problematic because, unlike current
> sources and/or resistors, they will not yield to capacitances at small
> time steps during convergence difficulties in a transient analysis.

My question is, what is it about the way LTSpice solves circuits that makes pure voltage sources so hard to deal with? In school, EEs learn about node voltage and mesh current methods, so an answer relating to these methods would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the circuit diagram that gives you this error?

Comment: Perhaps SPICE has a similar problem with current sources driving pure inductors as well. If capacitors resist instantaneous voltage changes, inductors resist instantaneous current changes. LTspice provides options to add a trivial non-ideal R to both inductors and capacitors to avoid these problems.

Comment: Probably why the  pulse voltage / currents sources default to relatively slow rise and fall times when you select "0" as the time, so a pure capacitance or inductance does not cause convergence problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because LTspice uses the [modified nodal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_nodal_analysis), where currents are analyzed, together with conductances & co. Mike Engelhardt, the author of LTspice, said repeatedly that voltage sources, which have (machine) zero internal resistance, pose problems in the matrix solver due to the inversion of this zero resistance. That's not to say voltage sources are prohibited, just that current sources will be superior in terms of convergence.

What is learned in school and how a solver in implemented in software, can be two very different things. And what you're quoting there is not part of the official help, but an addendum from a very knowledgeable member of the LTspice group. But you can read more straight from Mike, himself, from [this link](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/lt-journal-article/ltjournal-v24n4-01-df-spicedifferentiation-mikeengelhardt.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Your suggested aproaches with node voltage and mesh current is not a numeric approach such simulation software uses. Instead parts in the schematic are replaced with their appropriate functions. This super function is then examined for example for its dV/dt (change of voltage over time) or dI/dt (change of current over time) by doing small steps in time and finding solutions.

An uncharged capacitor at time 0 means zero resistance being immediatly exposed to the full voltage and flooded by the current beyond all means – this is a simulation and the voltage source assumed stiff (=no inner resistance). An infinite current and zero resistance is nothing easy when solving such equations to graph a circuit's switch on. Thus some real world tricks like inner resistance limit the current/ make the voltage collapse so a solution does not involve infinity and zero. (And so all voltage sources become current sources.)